# Turning off Slider load based on device width

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm working on a site for a client who bought a template and the issue is that now client wants the slider remove from hand held devices.

I know that we can use `<picture>` tag to assign different images based on screens size but what I'm trying to do here is to disable(by disable i mean canceling image load on mobile devices, not {display:none;} the slider loading all together from a certain screen size.

We'll probably have to create a script to call event assigned to that `<div>` to cancel its loading on for instance any screen size bellow 768px.
How can I do this?

(BTW I'm still learning JS .. any help is muchappreciated)
Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I have a simple solution to achieve your need. Below is the mobile check method.

```
// Mobile Device Check
function MobileDeviceCheck() {
    var mobileFlag = false;
    var isMobile = window.matchMedia("only screen and (max-width: 768px)");
    if ($(window).innerWidth() < 768 || (/Android|webOS|iPhone|iPod|BlackBerry|IEMobile|Opera Mini/i.test(navigator.userAgent))) {
        mobileFlag = true;
    }
    return mobileFlag;
}
```

Call the Above function to check the mobile device and do your necessary actions.

```
// Load Device Specific Actions
var mobileFlag = MobileDeviceCheck();        
if (mobileFlag == true) {
   // Do Your Actions
}
```

Comment: but how do i cancel loading of the parent div along with its childrens when the device width gets bellow 768..

ex: 
`<div class="ux_slider_wrapper">
 <div class="slider">
  <div role="banner"></div>
 </div>
</div>`

Comment: I tried this ...

`<script>
 if ($(window).innerWidth() <= 767) {
        document.getElementById("ux_slider").innerHTML = "";
    }
</script>`

but its not working ...